# RenderFile вместе с layout в yii

Tags: yii

Нужно отрендерить форму авторизации, но не в контроллере `Site`, а в другом. Через `renderFile` выводит только содержимое представления (голые формы), а надо еще `layout`, т.е. шапка, меню и т.д. Как быть?

Это `action` из контроллера `Site`:

```
public function actionLogin()
{
    $model=new LoginForm;

    // if it is ajax validation request
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='login-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }

    // collect user input data
    if(isset($_POST['LoginForm']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['LoginForm'];
        // validate user input and redirect to the previous page if valid
        if($model->validate() && $model->login())
            $this->redirect(Yii::app()->user->returnUrl);
    }
    // display the login form
    $this->render('login',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

Он вызывается из основного меню, т.е. `name/site/login`.

Задача: есть контроллер `Profile`. Из него нужно сделать

```
renderFile('path/views/site/login.php') или по-другому
```

Чтобы адрес был `name/profile/login` и вывелась форма авторизации по этому адресу, а не `name/site/login`.

Проблема в том, что такой `render` не вставляет этот `login.php` в шаблон `layout/column1.php`, т.е. не выводит шапку, меню и т.д. Он просто выводит содержимое `login.php`. Это логично, но как все же решить задачу по-другому? Т.е. по сути нужно вызвать просто `render`, т.к. только он вставит в шаблон форму. Но как это сделать из другого контроллера? Ведь `render` ищет представление в папке по имени контроллера...

Надеюсь, понятно объяснил...

Comment: а можно поподробнее?
куслк кода интересен, а именно - куда идет запрос от пользователя (контроллер) - и что он делает?

Comment: @Ale_x, обновил. Если что-то в вопросе непонятно, объясню) Литератор из меня никудышный...

Comment: впринципе понял) щас подумаем

Comment: так перенесите действие авторизации из контролера Site в контроллер Profile - что вам мешает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я, как правило, выношу форму авторизации в `AuthController`. В конфигах где нужно указываю `auth/login` и все пучком. Не понятно, почему вы решили использовать для это `renderFile` вместо `render`.

Однако, у `renderFile` и у `render` есть третий параметр, который при `true` вернет вам ваш шаблон, а не выведет его на экран.

Таким образом, если Вам нужно страница в нормальном виде:

```
$this->render('login', array(
    'form' => $this->renderFile('путь до файла', array(
        'model' => $model
    ))
));
```

Рекомендую посмотреть и разобраться как работает `render`, находится он в `CController`, может быть Вы решите его вовсе переписать под себя.

Comment: @VasyOk, такой рендер не прокатывает. Он ищет login в папке Profile. я смотрел как он работает в первую очередь. Я не знаю, как заставить его принять путь к представлению, чтобы он не искал в папке Profile, а в папке Site

Comment: А как насчет в место 'login'
написать '//путь_до_шаблона_относильно_директории_views' ?

Comment: $this->render('//site/login');

Comment: @VasyOk, действительно сработало! спасибо большое. просто не хотелось держать два одинаковых файла.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вот это то, что Вам надо [тут](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/yii--hmvc).

Answer (score 0):

Есть возможность сначала отрендерить в переменную, а потом передать это как простой текст:

```
public function actionAudit($id) {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $content = $this->renderFile(Yii::getPathOfAlias('application.views.site.audit') . '.php', array('model' => $model), true);
    $this->renderText($content);
}
```